How can i upload my code (where i am supossed to use API keys) into remote repo like github ...,etc
i have doing small project using html, JS with API keys in it.
At then , uploaded in GitHub with the code as it as , then GitGuardian throws an warning that i shared my API in public repo
can anyone suggest , how can i upload API keys directly into GitHub , so that i host in some websites
Some ways to tokenize or change my API key to upload directly to GitHub

Where are you planning to host your website? Most providers allow you to configure 'secrets' so that you don't have to upload your API key to Github, but instead use it as an environment variable.

You can use enivronment variables to save your api keys and other credentials. And if your uploading your code to git, you can use .gitignore to hide the environment variables file.
Reference links:
Environment variables : https://nodejs.org/en/learn/command-line/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs
gitignore : https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

i know this way, any other way to do this , is there any mechanism so that i can convert like tokenization and use it in public

@LeelaprasadLokesh I always use environment variables and  .gitignore for this type operations. And for your requirement i don't know what is exact solution, but there is an open-source secret management platform called infisical for manage our API Keys and other credentials. You can checkout the git repo of infisical using this link https://github.com/Infisical/infisical and I hope this will really useful for you!!

Github secrets is what you are looking for.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
